#  How to set default unix_socket_location when compiling PostgreSQL

Tags: linux, postgresql

I want to compile PostgreSQL and need to set a default for `unix_socket_location`. It should be `/var/run/postgresql` instead of `/tmp` like in the default build configuration.

In fact I just want to set a default for the `unix_socket_location` parameter, but I don't get where to set it. It is no `./configure option`, and I don't know where to look anymore, althought the docs say it can be changed during build time.

Where do I set a default for `unix_socket_location`?

Answer (score 3):

Edit `src/include/pg_config_manual.h`, change `DEFAULT_PGSOCKET_DIR`, (re-)build.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter you want to set is named `unix_socket_directory`. It can be configured in the `postgresql.conf` file. E.g.:

```
unix_socket_directory = '/var/run/postgresql'
```

You will probably need to restart PostgreSQL for a changed value of `unix_socket_directory` to take effect.

I don't know whether the default value can be changed at compile time, but if you set it in your `postgresql.conf`, the default will never be used.